# How to get exact alpha value in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alpha-channel

I need to know the exact alpha value of a pixel in Photoshop. I tried using the answer in this question ([Determine pixel alpha value in photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/182387/determine-pixel-alpha-value-in-photoshop)), but that gives me an opacity percentage such as 27%, which can be anything between 68 and 70, which all round to 27% after dividing by 255.

Is there any way to get the exact alpha value in Photoshop?

Comment: A question on this [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/182387/determine-pixel-alpha-value-in-photoshop) has already been asked in Super User

Comment: @spike_66 I know, and I even linked that question in my question. I'm looking for the exact alpha channel value from 0 to 255 rather than a percentage that can correspond to several alpha values.

Comment: Other question on this [topic](https://superuser.com/questions/182387/determine-pixel-alpha-value-in-photoshop) in Super User

Comment: @spike_66: That's the same link. It doesn't give me the exact value, but rather the value rounded to the nearest percent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the info box is set to RGB. You will see three numbers (which should all be equal for your alpha-channel and will correspond to the value you are looking for.