# Transparency shows as color when image is inserted in presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a png-file in which the background is transparent, it looks like this when opening it in GIMP:

[image]

I then try to insert it into a PowerPoint-presentation using:

> Insert > Pictures > This device > [Selecting the png-file]

And the background is no longer transparent:

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this? In the past I've never had any trouble inserting figures without a background, and I'm kinda stumped about what's going on.

[You can find a copy of the file here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cs3rBjOajO3KsMwZZlLAi27gxze90BUV/view?usp=sharing)

- edit - After struggling with this for 20 minutes, I did of course find a workaround by going to

> Picture format > Color > Set transparent color

minutes after posting this question, but I am still wondering what is causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: `Can someone please help me fix this?` is not a question about the problem ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Such a question requires posting the picture file online for us to examine.

Comment: I think this is more of a GIMP problem that a PowerPoint problem. A similar issue i ha a while ago was that the “transparency” isn't actually transparent but has like 10% opacity of a color in the background. 
As @harrymc says, you would have to provide us with your gimp file/ original image to help you with this

Comment: @chraebsli I've added a link to the file in the answer

Comment: Just from the screenshot I can see that the checkerboard looks darker than it should be from memory. Probably a low-opacity fill color in the 'transparent' area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your image, and the following are my findings from
an examination based on this
[PhotoShop method](https://superuser.com/questions/182387/determine-pixel-alpha-value-in-photoshop).

This has shown that the "transparent" background is not completely
transparent.

In effect, the opacity of your background is 3%.
To be completely transparent, it needs to be 0%.

Your workaround seems to be the correct solution.

You could also use an image editor in order to delete this 3% "color"
and make it truly 0%.

Comment: PowerPoint is handling that 3% opacity background color correctly. What makes you think otherwise? I would leave that statement out of this answer.

Comment: Huh, weird. Well, it explains what's happening at any rate. Thanks a lot for going to the trouble of checking for me.

Comment: @Romen: 3% transparency should not really be visible as a color, but in the poster's screenshot it looks like a gray color and is not like the real background.

Comment: 3% (which is ~7/255) is not a trivial amount of opacity, it absolutely would be visible even less than 1%. Powerpoint isn't rendering this wrong, it is exactly the color you should get with 3% opacity black mixing with a white background.

Comment: @Romen: I floated the poster's image over text in Word, and I need to squint very strongly to even try and detect the difference. The little bit of gray is much less pronounced than in the poster's screenshot. On the chance that the screenshot has changed somewhat when uploaded, I've taken this part out of my answer.